# Need to remove space to create URL?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I have a query pulling a bunch of city names. I need each of them to be linked... the link will look something like this:
www.sitename.com/city-new-york

Problem is, if I set the name to be the link of the names... some cities like "New York" has a space in them... and then the URL doesn't work right. 
How can I make it so that the spaces inside the name will be replaced with a "-"  so that it will read "city-new-york", right now I have this code but it links it as 
"city-new york"

```
<?php foreach ($cities as $city):?>
<li>
<a href="city-<?php echo $city['name']; ?>">
<?php echo $city['name']; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Also, I just have to add... that I don't have a choice, I HAVE to do it this way, because it's part of an existing script... I can't just add a separate column for URLs inside the db.

Comment: Just use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php), no need to replace spaces with "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str_replace` function allows you to replace characters in a string and `strtolower` will make the whole thing lowercase:

```
<?php foreach ($cities as $city):?>
<li>
<a href="city-<?php echo strtolower( str_replace(' ', '-', $city['name']) ); ?>">
<?php echo $city['name']; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: You are ABSOLUTELY awesome! Just what I needed, THANX!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function. Briefly, you need to encode a number of characters, not just spaces.

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_.
>   have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits
>   and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It is encoded the same way that
>   the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type

Note that your server will decode the parameters automatically. The above encodes for the HTTP request.